All the fonts must be embedded. This one is not: Helvetica
I am trying to sign a document with this code:
byte[] pdfBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(fileDriver.getContentBase64());
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfBytes));
        StampingProperties props = new StampingProperties();
        OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, fileOut, props.useAppendMode());

PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();

appearance
                .setReason(user.getFullName())
                .setLocation(user.getOffice())
                .setSignatureGraphic(imageData)
                .setReuseAppearance(false)
                .setPageRect(rect)
                .setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC)
                .setPageNumber(fileDriver.getLocation().getPage());
        signer.setFieldName(DateUtil.getDateNowString());

signer.signDetached(digest, pks, certificate, null, null, null, 0, CRYPTO_STANDARD);

Everything works fine except when the document arrives with a Adobe's  signature, in that case get the error
com.itextpdf.pdfa.exceptions.PdfAConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one is not: Helvetica
I already tried setting the font to the Document's Entity
InputStream resource = new ClassPathResource(path).getInputStream();
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(IOUtils.toByteArray(resource), PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED);
signer.getDocument().addFont(font);


actually if I see the Document structure inside signer element I could see the font defined
so, there is somethings that I forget.
PD. this error throws only when I try to sign a document, if a I send a text works fine
Best Regards
I am hoping to sign any kind of PDF document
